# How do I see the message for a http-response-code 406 exception

Tags: java, coldfusion

I'm using ColdFusion but I think this is more a java question. I'm making an xml post to a web service. When I attempt to read the response I receive an exception with an http response code of 406 from the following line:

```
var inputStreamReader = CreateObject("java","java.io.InputStreamReader").init(variables.connection.getInputStream());
```

The web service doc says the following for 406: "A 406 will be returned if the request was processed but did contained invalid or insufficient information to completed the API method. A message will be returned describing the error."

My question is, how do I retrieve or otherwise see what the message content contains?

Comment: How are you sending the xml post? Can we see that code? Are you using cfhttp? If so, `cfhttp.fileContent` would have the response.

Comment: Ditto. It would help to see the code. Specifically, what type of object is `variables.connection`? Also, can you post the full exception message/stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to see more code, as well as the exception. However, based on the fact that you are using `getInputStream`, I would guess you are using an [HTTPURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html), rather than cfhttp. If so, you need to check the returned status code before processing the response. Here is why:

If the request succeeds, the response is written to the [input stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream%28%29). Otherwise, it is written to the [error stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29) (that is probably where your error "message" is ending up). So you need to add some logic that reads the appropriate stream based on the HTTP status code returned.

From your comments, I assume you already know how to read an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and return a string. Just wrap that logic in a custom function named `streamToString`, then you can re-use it like so:

```
  // extract status code and message
  variables.result.code = variables.connection.getResponseCode();
  variables.result.message = variables.connection.getResponseMessage();

  // Simplified example, adjust as needed
  if (variables.result.code == variables.connection.HTTP_OK) {
      variables.result.text = streamToString(variables.connection.getInputStream());
  }
  else {
      variables.result.error = streamToString(variables.connection.getErrorStream());
  }

  // show results
  WriteDump(variables.result);
```

Comment: Perfect, that is what I needed. I'm using the signpost oauth library and it works with HTTPURLConnection. I can post a little more if someone wants to see but this answered my question. Thanks!