# Does ColdFusion 11 support body content for HTTP DELETE verb

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, http-delete, cfhttp

The below script block on ColdFUsion 11 has `GetHttpRequestData().content` as hello

If I change the verb to DELETE it is empty.

So ...

- Does ColdFusion not support this when making requests via `cfhttp`?
- Is this the wrong way?
- Is there a workaround?

Code:

```
cfhttp(method="POST", charset="utf-8", url="http://x/showrequest.cfm",   result="result" ) {
    cfhttpparam(name="body", type="body", value="hello");
}

writeOutput(result.filecontent);abort;
```

Comment: The body content is not required for DELETE requests - http://stackoverflow.com/a/299696/1636917

Comment: @Miguel-F - True, though I suspect some API's do use it. Sounds like the OP may be working with such an API and that cfhttp may not return the value (which would not surprise me).

Comment: You may be correct @Leigh.  It is hard to tell with the lack of detail in the question.

Comment: The API is cloudflares and it requires a message body for the delete operation, https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-individual-files-by-url-and-cache-tags

Comment: Did you search the bug database? Just guessing, but I suspect cfhttp does not send a "body" with DELETE requests. Since it is not required, that feature may not be implemented.  If that is the case, you may need to use another tool, ie curl, urlconnection, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Work around was to use java (shiver). Im sure there are helper libs to do this more succinctly but here it is.

```
<cfscript>
var u = createObject("java", "java.net.URL").init("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/#site.zoneId#/purge_cache");
var req = u.openConnection();
req.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
req.setDoOutput(true);
req.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json" );
req.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Email", "xxxxx" );
req.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Key", "xxxx" );
var os = req.getOutputStream();

os.write(javaCast("string",'{"files":#serializeJSON(urls)#}').getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.close();
ret = req.getResponseMessage();

var i = req.getInputStream();
var br = createObject("java",   "java.io.BufferedReader").init(createObject("java", "java.io.InputStreamReader").init(i));
var sb = createObject("java", "java.lang.StringBuilder").init();

var line = br.readLine();
while(!isNull(line)){
    sb.append(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}
req.disconnect();


</cfscript>
<cfdump var="req.getResponseCode() = #req.getResponseCode()#">
<cfdump var="#ret#">
<cfdump var="#sb.toString()#">
```

Comment: Do not forget to check the status code and error stream, if needed, so you know if an unexpected error occurred.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153249/how-do-i-see-the-message-for-a-http-response-code-406-exception/18154731#18154731